# Whenever i declare an enum, it won't compile

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, enums

Whenever I declare an `enum`, it simply won't compile. My code looks like this:

```
private enum race {HUMAN, ORC, GOBLIN, UNDEAD}

// The name of the player
string playerName;

// The Health Points of the player. Is to be modified  a LOT. Keep that in mind!
int HP = 100;

// Made to test if the name chosen i the right one
bool nameIsRight = false;

cout("Hello fair traveler!\n\n");
cout("It has come to my knowledge, that you, a puny warrior, is up for the challenge, that is killing the dragon\n\n");

cout("Our records seems to be damaged. What was your name again?\n\n");
cout("Enter your name: ");

// Sets playerName equal to the line entered by the player, turned into a string to prevent errors
playerName = Console.ReadLine().ToString();

cout("\n");

do
{
    string test;
    cout("Are you sure that is the right name? (y/n)\n");
    test = Console.ReadLine();
    cout("\n");
    if (test.ToLower() == "y")
    {
        nameIsRight = true;
    }
    else if (test.ToLower() == "n")
    {
        cout("What is your name then?\n");
        playerName = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    cout("\n");
} while (nameIsRight == false);

cout("So, your name is " + playerName + "? That is a name i haven't heard in a long time!\n\n");
cout("Just for the record, we need your race. Hope you don't mind telling it again.\n\n");
cout("1: Human\n\n2: ");
```

> Error 1   } expected  C:\Users\Herbstein\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\simpleRPGConsole\simpleRPGConsole\Program.cs   12  10  simpleRPGConsole
>
> Error 2   Method must have a return type  C:\Users\Herbstein\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\simpleRPGConsole\simpleRPGConsole\Program.cs   25  13  simpleRPGConsole
>
> Error 3   Type expected   C:\Users\Herbstein\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\simpleRPGConsole\simpleRPGConsole\Program.cs   25  18  simpleRPGConsole
>
> Error 4   Method must have a return type  C:\Users\Herbstein\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\simpleRPGConsole\simpleRPGConsole\Program.cs   26  13  simpleRPGConsole
>
> Error 5   Type expected   C:\Users\Herbstein\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\simpleRPGConsole\simpleRPGConsole\Program.cs   26  18  simpleRPGConsole
>
> Error 6   Method must have a return type  C:\Users\Herbstein\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\simpleRPGConsole\simpleRPGConsole\Program.cs   28  13  simpleRPGConsole
>
> Error 7   Type expected   C:\Users\Herbstein\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\simpleRPGConsole\simpleRPGConsole\Program.cs   28  18  simpleRPGConsole
>
> Error 8   Method must have a return type  C:\Users\Herbstein\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\simpleRPGConsole\simpleRPGConsole\Program.cs   29  13  simpleRPGConsole
>
> Error 9   Type expected   C:\Users\Herbstein\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\simpleRPGConsole\simpleRPGConsole\Program.cs   29  18  simpleRPGConsole
>
> Error 10  Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration C:\Users\Herbstein\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\simpleRPGConsole\simpleRPGConsole\Program.cs   32  24  simpleRPGConsole
>
> Error 11  Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration C:\Users\Herbstein\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\simpleRPGConsole\simpleRPGConsole\Program.cs   32  42  simpleRPGConsole
>
> Error 12  Method must have a return type  C:\Users\Herbstein\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\simpleRPGConsole\simpleRPGConsole\Program.cs   32  45  simpleRPGConsole
>
> Error 13  Method must have a return type  C:\Users\Herbstein\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\simpleRPGConsole\simpleRPGConsole\Program.cs   34  13  simpleRPGConsole
>
> Error 14  Type expected   C:\Users\Herbstein\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\simpleRPGConsole\simpleRPGConsole\Program.cs   34  18  simpleRPGConsole
>
> Error 15  Method must have a return type  C:\Users\Herbstein\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\simpleRPGConsole\simpleRPGConsole\Program.cs   39  17  simpleRPGConsole
>
> Error 16  Type expected   C:\Users\Herbstein\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\simpleRPGConsole\simpleRPGConsole\Program.cs   39  22  simpleRPGConsole
>
> Error 17  Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration C:\Users\Herbstein\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\simpleRPGConsole\simpleRPGConsole\Program.cs   40  22  simpleRPGConsole
>
> Error 18  Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration C:\Users\Herbstein\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\simpleRPGConsole\simpleRPGConsole\Program.cs   40  40  simpleRPGConsole
>
> Error 19  Method must have a return type  C:\Users\Herbstein\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\simpleRPGConsole\simpleRPGConsole\Program.cs   41  17  simpleRPGConsole
>
> Error 20  Type expected   C:\Users\Herbstein\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\simpleRPGConsole\simpleRPGConsole\Program.cs   41  22  simpleRPGConsole
>
> Error 21  Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration C:\Users\Herbstein\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\simpleRPGConsole\simpleRPGConsole\Program.cs   42  33  simpleRPGConsole
>
> Error 22  Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration C:\Users\Herbstein\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\simpleRPGConsole\simpleRPGConsole\Program.cs   44  33  simpleRPGConsole
>
> Error 23  A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods   C:\Users\Herbstein\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\simpleRPGConsole\simpleRPGConsole\Program.cs   46  17  simpleRPGConsole
>
> Error 24  A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods   C:\Users\Herbstein\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\simpleRPGConsole\simpleRPGConsole\Program.cs   52  15  simpleRPGConsole
>
> Error 25  Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected   C:\Users\Herbstein\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\simpleRPGConsole\simpleRPGConsole\Program.cs   57  9   simpleRPGConsole

What should i do to help this? I don't wanna make something like this without enums!

Herbstein

Comment: From the error messages it seems like the code is written directly in a class, check that all your executing code is inside methods and that all brackets are closed..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not showing the entire code, but your `enum` appears to be in the middle of a function. Don't do that.

Also, your methods need to be in a `class`. Check out some good examples.

Also, `cout` doesn't exist in C# - that's a C++ thing, and you're not using it right in any language. C# uses `Console.WriteLine`.

```
namespace MyApp
{
    // Every method (function) must be in a class
    class MyProgram
    {
        // This is where code execution begins
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");

            string playerName = GetPlayerName();
        }

        static string GetPlayerName()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Some cliche narrative here. Name?");

            return Console.ReadLine();
        }

        // We can also make nested class/struct/enum definitions that are
        // "private" to the containing class.
        private enum APrivateEnum { Foo, Bar }
    }

    enum Race { Human, Orc, Goblin, Undead }
}
```

Comment: +1. Basic "heck, read the basic syntax of C#" reality check, sadly.

Comment: I know the basic syntax, i just didn't know it should be outside functions. That you so much for the help!

Comment: @user3350284 Alrighty. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Remember to up-vote any answer that helped, and accept that answer that solved your problem.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart The cout is a function i defined myself, to make the syntax more read-able to me. I'm not a complete beginner at C#, but i've mostly been prtototyping in Unity.

Comment: @Herbstein Fair enough. However, I would caution you against writing such functions to make it look like other languages. It is usually best to learn the best-practice for a language and stick with it, if you ever plan to interact with anyone with your code. In this case, that means sticking with the (admittedly more verbose) `Console.WriteLine`. Just a suggestion, it's your code afterall.

Answer (score 1):

Try define the enum outside of a method.